# how to alter column of a dataframe with different values and by various condition in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame where I want to alter the column "conf" with different values according to the condition satisfied.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"conf":[100,100,100,100],
            "i":[-2,3,-3,10],
            "o":[12,13,14,16],
            "n":[6,4,6,1],
           "id":[1.4,2,1.3,1.7],
            "od":[2,3,2.5,8],
            "nd":[2,3,2.4,-0.9],
           "iwr":[60,60,45,65],
           "owr":[65,88,90,78],
           "nwr":[67,63,60,60]})
df
```

i want to do this but i am doing it in the wrong way beacuse i am passing series to if condition, which is not the right way.

```
def column_alter(df):
    if (((df["id"]>1.5) & (df["iwr"]>1.5)):
        if (((df["od"]>1.5) & (df["nd"]>1.5)) & ((df["owr"]>60) & (df["nwr"]>60))):
                df["conf"]= df["conf"]
        else:
            df["conf"]= df["conf"]*0.5
    else:
        if (((df["od"]>1.5) & (df["nd"]>1.5)) & ((df["owr"]>60) &(df["nwr"]>60))):
            df["conf"]= df["conf"]
        else:
            df["conf"]= df["conf"]*0.25
    return df
```

Required Output: I want to return whole dataframe with modified Conf value  i.e [100,100,25,50]

Comment: i have edited the question it shouldn't be passing dataframe ... now it is passing booleans. Could you please look at it again @jezrael

Comment: I got it. First I dont find last row - expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For else is possible invert mask by `~`, chain mask by `&` and multiple with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
m0 = (df["id"]>1.5) & (df["iwr"]>1.5)
m1 = (df["od"]>1.5) & (df["nd"]>1.5) & (df["owr"]>60) & (df["nwr"]>60)

df.loc[m0 & ~m1, "conf"] *= 0.5
df.loc[~m0 & ~m1, "conf"] *= 0.25
print (df)
    conf   i   o  n   id   od   nd  iwr  owr  nwr
0  100.0  -2  12  6  1.4  2.0  2.0   60   65   67
1  100.0   3  13  4  2.0  3.0  3.0   60   88   63
2   25.0  -3  14  6  1.3  2.5  2.4   45   90   60
3   50.0  10  16  1  1.7  8.0 -0.9   65   78   60
```

Another solution with [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m0 = (df["id"]>1.5) & (df["iwr"]>1.5)
m1 = (df["od"]>1.5) & (df["nd"]>1.5) & (df["owr"]>60) & (df["nwr"]>60)

df['conf'] *= np.select([m0 & ~m1, ~m0 & ~m1], [0.5, 0.25], default=1)
#long alternative
#df['conf'] = np.select([m0 & ~m1, ~m0 & ~m1], 
                        [df['conf'] * 0.5, df['conf'] * 0.25], default=df['conf'])
print (df)
    conf   i   o  n   id   od   nd  iwr  owr  nwr
0  100.0  -2  12  6  1.4  2.0  2.0   60   65   67
1  100.0   3  13  4  2.0  3.0  3.0   60   88   63
2   25.0  -3  14  6  1.3  2.5  2.4   45   90   60
3   50.0  10  16  1  1.7  8.0 -0.9   65   78   60
```